# Add Solid State Drive to Toshiba Satellite P755

Tags: laptop, ssd, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba P755 laptop, and I'd like to add a SSD to it. I don't know if it's possible (doesn't look like it has another SATA adapter) or if there are other solutions.

Do laptops have space for adding a secondary disk, or do I have to replace the existent one completely? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to replace the existing one if the manufacturer doesn't explicitly specify that there's room for expansion. For your laptop, [that does not seem to be the case](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/P750/P755-S5269/).

Also depending on your machine, you may void your warranty. With my laptop that is the case because I would break a seal opening it up to reach the HDD, but my sister has one where you can just remove it (and replace it) as you please. Do note that the replacement you buy may not fit exactly, but unfortunately I can't tell you more concerning that since I'm not sure.